# Join between a collection and a table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a problem with procedures in PL/SQL. I have a public procedure declared in a package and I want to call another procedure(private) inside the first one.

```
PROCEDURE show_notesforstudent (number_id IN number) as
    ...
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The notes for the student with number_id X are: '|| Y);

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('here is the call for the private procedure');
    erase_student(number_id);
END;
```

This code is a general example, my code is bigger and I can't put it all here. Here is only the main idea.
For this call I face this error: "Error(31,5): PLS-00313: 'erase_student' not declared in this scope".

The implementation of erase_student procedure is:

```
PROCEDURE erase_student(n_id students.number_id%type) AS
  student_inexistent EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(student_inexistent, -20002);
  counter integer;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(nmber_id) INTO counter FROM studens where number_id = n_id;
  IF counter = 0 THEN
      raise student_inexistent;
  END IF;
  DELETE FROM students WHERE number_id = n_id;
  EXCEPTION
  WHEN student_inexistent THEN
      raise_application_error (-20002, 'Student with number_id' || n_id ||        '     doesn't exists in database');
END stergere_student;`
```

Comment: Declare the `erase_student` procedure before the `show_notesforstudent` or use a forward declaration of the `erase_student`'s header at the start of the procedure.

Comment: Perhaps `erase_student` doesn't exist because of the syntax errors in `erase_students`. It appears that the table name in the `SELECT COUNT(*)...` should be `students` rather than `studens`. Also, the name of the procedure (`erase_student`) doesn't match the name on the `END stergere_student` statement. Possibly an issue when translating (from Romanian?). Also, in the `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR` call, the apostrophe in `doesn't` should be doubled (`doesn''t`) so you get one apostrophe in the string literal. Best of luck.

Comment: I'm also confused about how the title and the question relate.  In your title, you're talking about wanting to join to a collection.  I don't see anything in the body of your question that references a collection.

Comment: I made a mistake..I wanted to post another question and the title remains..sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets simplify your code and make it syntactically correct:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE package_name
AS
  PROCEDURE show_notesforstudent (number_id IN number);
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY package_name
AS
  PROCEDURE show_notesforstudent (number_id IN number)
  AS
  BEGIN
      erase_student(number_id);
  END;

  PROCEDURE erase_student(n_id NUMBER) AS BEGIN NULL; END; 
END;
/
```

However, it still won't compile as we get `PLS-00313: 'ERASE_STUDENT' not declared in this scope`. It can be fixed by re-organising the package to ensure that the private procedure is declared before it is called; like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY package_name
AS
  PROCEDURE erase_student(n_id NUMBER) AS BEGIN NULL; END; -- Header and body

  PROCEDURE show_notesforstudent (number_id IN number)
  AS
  BEGIN
      erase_student(number_id);
  END;
END;
/
```

However, if you want to keep the order of the procedures in the package then you could just use a forward declaration to declare the header for the private procedure before it is called and declare the body afterwards; like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY package_name
AS
  PROCEDURE erase_student(n_id NUMBER); -- Header only

  PROCEDURE show_notesforstudent (number_id IN number)
  AS
  BEGIN
      erase_student(number_id);
  END;

  PROCEDURE erase_student(n_id NUMBER) AS BEGIN NULL; END; -- Header and body
END;
/
```